# Path length of a satellite signal

Tags: electrical-engineering, mathematics

I am trying to work out the length of the Rsv, but I dont understand how to go about this. If the length R is known and the angle EL is known how do I go about solving for this length. I was given some formulas but again I feel there is too many unknowns

I have thought about trigonometry and sine and cosine, but still am unsure. Any help would be great. The image is shown below for the problem
[image]

Comment: SE Space Exploration might be able to help with this.

Comment: 2 sides and the included angle: law of cosine.

Answer (score 0):

The [Law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) can be used to find the length of the third side of a triangle when two sides and the included angle are known.

$$R_{SV}^2 = R^2+R_E^2 -2R_{SV}R_E\cos(90+\theta_{EL})$$